how to print multiple responses in business central workbench
Closed. This question needs details or clarity. It is not currently accepting answers.
Add details and clarify the problem you’re solving. This will help others answer the question. You can edit the question or post a new one.
Closed 5 days ago.
Request :
{ "lookup": null, "commands": [ { "insert" : { "object":{ "ActualPrice":{ "customer":"ramanathan" "discount":15, "ruleName":7 } }, "disconnected":false, "out-identifier":"Applicant", "return-object":true, "entry-point":"DEFAULT" } },{ "fire-all-rules" : { } } ] }
Response :
{ "type" : "SUCCESS", "msg" : "Container fimandate_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT successfully called.", "result" : { "execution-results" : { "results" : [ { "value" : {"com.myspace.fimandate.ActualPrice":{ "customer" : "ramanathan", "discount" : 15, "actualPrice" : 2700, "ruleName" : 7 }}, "key" : "Applicant" } ], "facts" : [ { "value" : {"org.drools.core.common.DefaultFactHandle":{ "external-form" : "0:1:2070368216:2070368216:1:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:com.myspace.fimandate.ActualPrice" }}, "key" : "Applicant" } ] } } }
in given request two rules are fired but in my response it print only one .
i want to print all matched rules for the given request. what need to change

Did you copy-paste the contents of a closed question?
